# Magento stock an prices in 0

Tags: magento

I have a process that makes an update on DB for Magento stock and prices. But what I exactly need to do is to set both prices and stocks in 0 before start the update. Now I have the following code and it works, but is too slow.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
foreach ($product as $key => $valor) {
   $valor->setPrice(0);
   $valor->save();
}


$stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->getCollection();
foreach ($stock as $key) {
    $key->setQty(0);
    $key->setData('is_in_stock', 1);
    $key->save();

}
```

Could you helpme to improve it?.

Kind regards!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the index process to "update manual".By default magento reindex the site every time you make a change to your products adding another process to your task.If you make it "Update manually" the process could be faster.